# Failed to upload to website with php throws no errors

Tags: php, file, upload

I am trying to upload a csv file and read the temp directly or even to write it to the uploads directory that I created. I am getting output with my echo  that i put in for debugging but I still get no file output or saved file when I try and upload it

```
  <?php

    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";
    $file = $_FILES[csv][tmp_name]; 

    $handle  = fopen($file,"r");

    echo "error:" .$_FILES['file1']['error'] . "<br>";
   if( move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])){
       echo "sucess<br>";
    }
      else
      {
      echo "FAILED<br>";
     }

      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];

   $data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","");
   do { 


       // mysql_query("INSERT INTO contacts (contact_first, contact_last, contact_email) VALUES 

               echo $data[0];
                echo $data[1];
                 echo $data[2];
                  echo $data[3];
                   echo $data[4];

        //"); 

    } while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'")); 
    ?>




The output from the echo is 
Upload: TestData (1).csv
Type: application/vnd.ms-excel
Size: 609.893554688 kB
Stored in: /tmp/php7MixBu
error:
FAILED
```

Comment: Show your `<form>` tag

Comment: var_dump(is_writable("upload/")); - Is it true?

Comment: I see `$_FILES["file"]` then `$_FILES[csv]` then `$_FILES['file1']` gee, how could it not go wrong?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html > 
<html> 
<head> 
<meta charset="UTF-8" /> 
<title>Import Data File </title> 
</head> 

<body> 

<html>
<body>

<form action="includes/importfunctions.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html> 

</body> 
</html>  this is the form

Comment: I fixed the file1 error and i get error:0

Comment: Thanks Fred found the idiot issue

Comment: Fred -ii- was more observant and had the answer it was the csv thing. is there an idiot badge he can give me?